# Pi 3 nextcloud server and NAS

Tags: pi-3, samba, storage, nextcloud

Is it possible to use something like dietpi, install nextcloud as well as have a NAS in the same thing accessing the same files? What I would like is a system where I can access the NAS via my Linux or windows machines through something like samba share and also be able to access the same files via nextcloud on let's say a phone via the nextcloud app. If this is possible please can you guide me on how to do this? Thank you.

### Edit 1:

Seems like people are misunderstanding my question.
What I wanted to have is a **single** raspberry pi 3 with a samba Nas on it as well as it being a nextcloud server **at the same time on the same device**

### Edit 2:

Would anyone know of any tools that can help me achieve this on a raspberry pi 3? If this is with dietpi then brilliant.

Comment: There's no reason to believe this *isn't* possible, by which I mean, you have a general purpose, multi-core, multi-tasking platform with a reasonable amount of RAM.  I've done something pretty similar using dropbox and sshfs (mounting the dropbox directory with sshfs, making the contents convenient for both Android and linux clients). How well it will do if you ramp up the numbers of users I dunno, but just for personal use this should be fine.

Comment: @goldilocks all I want is for my house, which me, my brother and parents, so 4 people. Also if you know of any tools that might help with this then that would be great.

Comment: I've never tried nextcloud on a pi, but it has a lot of moving parts; probably your best bet is to use a nextcloud oriented distro and then configure the samba server in, that part should be quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I looked at this nextcloud supported entries in fstab as normal.

So you could add a line along this format:

```
//192.168.1.20/nassharename /var/nc_data/<user>/files cifs user,rw,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0
```

Where

- 192.168.1.20 is the IP address of the NAS - do not use the name as fstab sometimes fails to find it in my network
- is the next cloud user
- cifs is the NAS share type.  Not sure if you can pick up AFP shares here
- user,rw etc are the rights you want to pass up to the users on the cloud share (noexec is a good idea).

If you do not want to edit fstab, you can use the External Storage Support application AFTER you have enabled it on the apps screen:

- Go to **add storage**
- Enter a share name
- Drop down the new box - select NAS share type
- Drop down the correct authentication type
- Enter security details

See [here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/admin_manual/configuration_files/external_storage_configuration_gui.html) for pictures of the latest version (18 as at early May 2020)

Comment: Not exactly what I was after but I have now updated my question to better phrase this.